# Typescript library to be consumed by an external party using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, client

I have to develop a library using ideally TypeScript that will be consumed by one of our clients who is using JavaScript.  My question is how do I generate a valid .js file(s) from my .ts file that is not minified or anything and that can be consumed from .js clients.  Plus the methods I expose in my .ts file(s) should have the same names in the generated .js file(s)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the TypeScript compiler first.
You can do that with NPM:

```
npm install -g typescript
```

Than you can compile your TypeScript files to JavaScript files with

```
tsc helloworld.ts helloworld.js
```

But I would advice against using TypeScript as language for a library that will be used in a JavaScript environment, because some TypeScript "features" just work within TypeScript, e.g. private properties are public after compiling to JavaScript.